# After Trigger Not getting updated Table Value in trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

This is my code i am getting old StartDateUtc and EndDateUtc After Second update in my trigger

First Time when i updated my value its work fine but second time its taking old value
 please give me some Suggestion for it

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[NewsUpdateTrigger]'))
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[NewsUpdateTrigger]
    GO
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NewsUpdateTrigger]
           ON [dbo].[News] 
   FOR  UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN


 SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @EntityId INT
   DECLARE @EntityName varchar(Max)
   DECLARE @IsPublish bit
   DECLARE @LanguageId int
   DECLARE @StoreId int
   DECLARE @InTime Datetime  
   SELECT @EntityName='News'



                     DECLARE @StatDate DateTime
                     DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

                     SELECT @EntityId = DELETED.Id FROM DELETED 
                     SELECT @IsPublish = DELETED.Published FROM DELETED 
                     SELECT @StatDate= DELETED.StartDateUtc FROM DELETED 
                      SELECT @EndDate= DELETED.EndDateUtc FROM DELETED 

             IF      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Incremental_Solr_Custom where EntityName='News' and EntityId  = @EntityId)
             BEGIN
                     --If StartDateUtc and  EndDateUtc expire Manually Set the is Publish=False
              IF     EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED  WHERE StartDateUtc NOT BETWEEN Cast( GETDate() as date) AND Cast( GETDate() as date)
                     AND Cast( GETDate() as date) NOT BETWEEN StartDateUtc AND EndDateUtc )
            BEGIN

                     UPDATE Incremental_Solr_Custom SET SolrStatus =1,IsPublish=0 WHERE EntityId = @EntityId AND EntityName='News';
                     Insert into TriggerTesterTable(ErrorMethodName)values(' If StartDateUtc and  EndDateUtc expire Set the is Publish=False  '+ cast( @StatDate as  varchar) + '   '+cast( @EndDate as  varchar))
             END

                     --StartDate and EndDate is Not expire Get From News Table
             IF      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED  WHERE StartDateUtc  BETWEEN Cast( GETDate() as date) AND Cast( GETDate() as date)
                     OR Cast( GETDate() as date) BETWEEN StartDateUtc AND EndDateUtc)
             BEGIN
                     SELECT @IsPublish = DELETED.Published FROM DELETED 
                     UPDATE Incremental_Solr_Custom SET SolrStatus =1,IsPublish=@IsPublish WHERE EntityId = @EntityId AND EntityName='News';
                     Insert into TriggerTesterTable(ErrorMethodName)values('StartDate and EndDate is Not expire Get IsPublish from News  '+cast( @StatDate as  varchar) + '   '+cast( @EndDate as  varchar));
             END

     END
```

END

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Then how can i get the value from Updated table without using the Deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating update trigger but you are using DELETED table (also called magic table )instead of INSERTED table.
Please refer to this link it may helpful for you https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/12187/use-of-dml-dll-and-logon-trigger-in-sql

Moreover, your can use the concept of 'Instead of trigger' because there insert is basis of some condition.

Answer (score 0):

use this SELECT * FROM INSTEAD where you put SELECT * FROM DELETED